# How do I get TABLE OF TOURNAMENT POSITIONS according to score table

Tags: mysql

Buen dia Comunidad.

Good morning Community.

I am having doubts about how to obtain the POSITION CHART of the following SCORE table in MYSQL.

1: This is my table where the user records the escort of each sport played.
[image]

2: Now this is where I have doubts, how do I get the POSITION CHART according to the attached model where the following is calculated: PJ = Matches played PG = Matches Won PP = Lost Matches PE = Draws Matched GF = Goals For GC = Goals Against DFG = Total Goal Difference = where the winning team obtains 3 Points.

.[image]

I wait for your kind support

I could only make the amount of encounter that 1 team has made

```
select category, report, gender, Team1, count (*) from score where Team1 = 'red' and category = 'CAT 3'
```

Comment: MySQL 8.0 has `RANK()`, etc.

Comment: Unclear. Sample output does not match to sample source data. For example, there is 3 records for `Cat 3`+`Futbol` for `ROJO` (id = 3,8,9) whereas only 2  games in output (id = 3 is skipped). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking the task and sample data and ignoring sample output...

For MySQL 8+ :

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT categoria,ndeporte,equipo1,score1,equipo3,score3
FROM score
UNION ALL
SELECT categoria,ndeporte,equipo3,score3,equipo1,score1
FROM score
)
SELECT UPPER(equipo1) EQUIPOS, 
       COUNT(*) PJ, 
       SUM(score1>score3) PG, 
       SUM(score1<score3) PP, 
       SUM(score1=score3) PE, 
       SUM(score1) GF,
       SUM(score3) GC,
       SUM(score1-score3) DfG,
       SUM(3*SIGN(score1-score3)) TOTAL
FROM cte 
WHERE categoria = 'CAT 3'
  AND ndeporte = 'Futbol'
  GROUP BY UPPER(equipo1);
```

... and for MySQL 5+ :

```
SELECT UPPER(equipo1) EQUIPOS, 
       COUNT(*) PJ, 
       SUM(score1>score3) PG, 
       SUM(score1<score3) PP, 
       SUM(score1=score3) PE, 
       SUM(score1) GF,
       SUM(score3) GC,
       SUM(score1-score3) DfG,
       SUM(3*SIGN(score1-score3)) TOTAL
FROM ( SELECT categoria,ndeporte,equipo1,score1,equipo3,score3
       FROM score
       UNION ALL
       SELECT categoria,ndeporte,equipo3,score3,equipo1,score1
       FROM score) cte 
WHERE categoria = 'CAT 3'
  AND ndeporte = 'Futbol'
  GROUP BY UPPER(equipo1);
```

If you need the data for all `categoria` and/or `ndeporte` then add them to output fields list and GROUP BY clause, and remove from WHERE clause (or edit if you need the result for some values only).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c8e68df5dacb42c8bf6b15cdb0e230ce)

Comment: If it is very true, if the team loses 2 matches in this case turquoise is -6, but for the user it should be total = 0

Comment: modify in this part to avoid negatives and calculate the total well: }SUM (3 * SIGN (score1-score3> = 0)) TOTAL

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: @kenny `SIGN(score1-score3>=0)` == `(score1>=score3)`